# inline form element for screen less than 768

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a form which i implemented form-inline and [bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) . That is working fine for screen width> 768, however when i try to resize it to ipad size, it is no longer inline. How to solve my problems:

1. because i set `data-width="auto"` for bootstrap-select, it is no 100% (1 column) or 50%(2 columns, which is most ideal in ipad case to display two select box side by side). i tried many ways, e.g. resetting the attribute data-width to "50%" then call `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker(render);`, but failed, what to do?
2. the checkboxes are auto break into four lines, for ipad size, i think it is better to keep them in one line, what can i do?

JSFiddle links: http://jsfiddle.net/nc16ntwq/ as the codes cant appear

```html
<form class="form-inline" style="margin:10px 0px;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select id="date" name="date" class="date selectpicker"  data-width="auto">
            <option value='01'>01</option>
            <option value='02'>02</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select id="dateYear" name="dateYear" class="date selectpicker"  data-width="auto">
            <option value="1984">1984</option>
            <option value="1985">1985</option>
            <option value="1986">1986</option>
            <option value="1987">1987</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select id="toDate" name="toDate" class="date selectpicker" data-width="auto">
            <option value='01'>01</option>
            <option value='02'>02</option>
            <option value='03'>03</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select id="toDateYear" name="toDateYear" class="date selectpicker"  data-width="auto">
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
            <option value="2019" selected>2019</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
            <input id="v1" type="checkbox" checked> Value 1
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
            <input id="v2" type="checkbox" checked> value 2 
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
            <input id="v3" type="checkbox"> value 3
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
            <input id="v4" type="checkbox"> Values 4
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: strange, i cannot make my code appear

Comment: JSFIddle please ! or some code ...

Comment: anybody know what can i do? i click the edit,  the codes are there

Comment: jsfiddle link added.

Answer (score 0):

[**JSFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/3642/). I only do this for dropdown. Just add this to you CSS

```
.form-inline .form-group {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-bottom: 0;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```